# How to implement ajax in rails 4.0 for a simple multiplication operation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a beginner to rails.
What I'm trying to implement is simple:
I have two textboxes on the screen.In textbox1, I type in a number and click on the submit button.This submit button should perform an ajax request and then return a 'template' html which allows me to display the square of the number in textbox2.

Please help in understanding the naming conventions for the template/partial which is to be displayed when the ajax request is made

I know this question sounds incredibly dumb but rails is a tough framework to learn for a person who is a beginner to web development and I was unable to find a single tutorial on the internet which does this simple functionality. All the existing tutorials focus on retrieving data from the database which increases complexity and leaves me even more confused. The more I learn about rails, the more I realize that there is a lot more to learn.

I would appreciate detailed instructions on how to perform this task. If you feel that this question should be closed then please redirect me to some website where beginners are allowed to post questions.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with standard JS, like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.rb
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    val = $("#textbox1").val();
    square = val * val; // surely a function for this
    $("#textbox2").val(square);
});
```

If you wanted to use Ajax, you'd do this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: "your/endpoint",
      data: $("#textfield1").serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
          $("#textfield2").val(data);
      }
   });
});

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def action
       @return = params[:textfield1] 
       respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: @return.to_json }
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `remote: true` parameter

```
<%= form_tag action: '/calculate', method: :post, remote: true do %>
<%= text_field_tag 'x' %>
<%= text_field_tag 'y' %>
<%= submit_tag 'calculate' %>
```

This will render a form that will fetch it's result in ajax, of course substitute the letters with actual paths in your application.

You can then return javascript that does the rendering of the template